# COUNT number of rows in a GROUP on higher aggregate level

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out how many rows of a certain item exist in the table, e.g. in the following example for itemID 1 I need the result 5 (not 3, which is what I currently get). I am tempted to add TransactionID into the PARTITION BY clause, but that results in Msg 8120 since the query does not GROUP by TransactionID. Well, if it did then getting that count would be easy, but I do not want to group on Transaction Level. What can I do to get that ItemCount right? It must be so easy but I am banging my head.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (TransactionID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, CustomerID INT, ItemID INT);

INSERT INTO @t (CustomerID, ItemID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (1, 1);

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(*),
    ItemRowCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID)
FROM
    @t
GROUP BY
    CustomerID,
    ItemID
ORDER BY
    ItemID,
    CustomerID;
```

EDIT: I was overaggregating, I guess. Sebastian Meine got me on the track and his answer is right so I accepted it. However, this subquery works for my:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(*),
    ItemRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t x WHERE t.ItemID = x.ItemID)
FROM
    @t t
GROUP BY
    CustomerID,
    ItemID
ORDER BY
    ItemID,
    CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull your outer group count out of the actual group by query. The easiest way to do that is like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02c63/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl  (TransactionID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, CustomerID INT, ItemID INT);

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (CustomerID, ItemID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (1, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,SUM(Rows)OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId) ItemCnt
FROM(
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(*) 
FROM
    dbo.tbl
GROUP BY
    CustomerID,
    ItemID
)X
ORDER BY
    ItemID,
    CustomerID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02c63/1/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMERID | ITEMID | ROWS | ITEMCNT |
----------------------------------------
|          1 |      1 |    3 |       5 |
|          2 |      1 |    1 |       5 |
|          3 |      1 |    1 |       5 |
|          2 |      2 |    1 |       2 |
|          4 |      2 |    1 |       2 |
|          3 |      3 |    1 |       1 |
|          4 |      4 |    1 |       1 |
```

Notice that I add the inner counts together instead of recounting from scratch.

Comment: This produces the desired result. I was hoping that I do not have to change the FROM clause, since there is more than one such column where I need the total rowcount of in the actual query. I was hoping to re-partition in the SELECT. If there is not such solution, then this is the answer.

Comment: I don't think there can be a direct solution, as any aggregate gets to "see" only the rows of the current group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE or join to a sub-table (like this)

```
SELECT
    tbl.CustomerID,
    tbl.ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(*),
    ItemRowCount
FROM tbl
JOIN (SELECT ItemID, Count(*) as ItemRowCount
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY ItemID) t ON tbl.ItemID = t.ItemID
GROUP BY
    tbl.CustomerID,
    tbl.ItemID,
    ItemRowCount
ORDER BY
    tbl.ItemID,
    CustomerID;
```

or this

```
SELECT
    tbl.CustomerID,
    tbl.ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(*),
    MAX(ItemRowCount)
FROM tbl
JOIN (SELECT ItemID, Count(*) as ItemRowCount
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY ItemID) t ON tbl.ItemID = t.ItemID
GROUP BY
    tbl.CustomerID,
    tbl.ItemID
ORDER BY
    tbl.ItemID,
    CustomerID;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - yeah OVER can't do that on Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `count` and `group by`:

```
SELECT
    ItemID,
    ItemRowCount = COUNT(1)
FROM
    @t
GROUP BY
    ItemID
ORDER BY
    ItemID
```

or if you need attach total rows count and item row count to every row:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    ItemID,
    Rows = COUNT(1) over (),
    ItemRowCount = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID)
FROM
    @t
ORDER BY
    ItemID,
    CustomerID;
```

Comment: This produces potentially multiple rows per `CustomerID, ItemID` group.

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many rows of a certain item exist in the table, we may not need CustomerId. Use following query -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (TransactionID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, CustomerID INT, ItemID INT);

INSERT INTO @t (CustomerID, ItemID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (1, 1);

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT itemId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY itemId DESC) AS row_cnt FROM @t
)   

SELECT itemId, MAX(row_cnt) row_count FROM cte GROUP BY itemId
```

It will return -

```
itemId  row_count
1       5
2       2
3       1
4       1
```

And if is case you need customerId, the use -

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT customerId, itemId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY itemId DESC) AS row_cnt FROM @t
)   
SELECT customerId, itemId, MAX(row_cnt) item_count FROM cte GROUP BY CustomerID, itemId
```

It will return -

```
customerId  itemId  item_count 
1           1       5
2           1       2
3           1       3
2           2       1
4           2       2
3           3       1
4           4       1
```

Comment: This, like Sebastians approach, requires moving an aggregate function into the SELECT. Will become a huge query since I also require such counts for other columns.